# Mocking a nested function in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

How do I mock/spyOn the value of a function returned after calling another function? In the following example I would like to mock the resolved value for the 'get' method of `api.get()` but I've been having difficulty getting at that value with a jest mock or spyOn. The issue is that the `get` method is returned after the function is called as part of `axiosInstanceWrapper({})`.

axios-instance-wrapper.js:

```
...

const axiosInstanceWrapper = function(params) {
  ...
  const instance = axios.create(otherInstanceParams);
  ...
  return instance;
}

module.exports = axiosInstanceWrapper;
```

code:

```
import axiosInstanceWrapper from './axios-instance-wrapper';

const api = axiosInstanceWrapper({});
const result = api.get(MY_URL, myParams); <-- I want to mock this response
```

test file:

```
import axiosInstanceWrapper from './axios-instance-wrapper';


jest.mock('./axios-instance-wrapper', () => {
  return () => ({
    default: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      get: jest.fn()
    })
  });
});

...

test('', () => {
 const spy = jest.spyOn(axiosInstanceWrapper, 'get').mockResolvedValue({
      data: {
        customer: {
          subscriptionContracts: [],
          pageInfo: {
            hasNextPage: false,
            hasPreviousPage: false,
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Error I get on that line:

> Error: Cannot spy the get property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Other things I've tried:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(axiosInstanceWrapper.default, 'get').mockResolvedValue({
  ...
});
```